# Show a contributor's number of commits and lines of code contributed

Tags: git, github

I would like to view a summary of my total number of commits and total number of lines of code which I have committed to a particular repository on GitHub. Is there any way to do this using either: GitHub, Git Shell on Windows, or another tool which easily works on Windows or in a web browser?

Here is my current strategy:

**Commits**

1. Go to the URL https://github.com/repositoryname/projectname/commits?author=myname with Google Chrome
2. Hit Ctrl+F and type in the word "committed", to see the number of times this word appears on the page
3. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click the Older button. Repeat from step 2 and keep increasing the total count until done.

**Lines of Code**

1. Open Git Hub and go to the repo directory
2. `git log --author="myemail" --oneline --shortstat > gitstat.log`
3. Maybe I will write a little program to tally up the number of insertions, or count it by hand

Surely there must be a more convenient way of doing this? Note: I am looking for an answer that does not require bash, and is easily accessible to Windows users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On GitHub’s repo summary bar, click the contributor count:

[image: screenshot of repo summary bar with “contributors” highlighted]

[The contributor list](https://github.com/github/linguist/graphs/contributors) includes number of commits, lines added, and lines deleted for each person.

[image: screenshot of contributor list]

Alternatively, to count commits with just the Git CLI, you can use `git shortlog --summary`:

```
~/src/linguist $ git shortlog --summary --numbered --no-merges
   607  Joshua Peek
   568  Arfon Smith
   321  Paul Chaignon
   245  Ted Nyman
   132  Brandon Keepers
   131  Adam Roben
    81  Alhadis
    80  Lars Brinkhoff
     ⋮
```

This doesn’t have GitHub’s advantage of grouping multiple name/e-mail combos belonging to the same user, mind.

Comment: Why is the shortlog showing me at a higher number of commits than the web-based method?

Comment: @PatrickParker: GitHub doesn’t include merge commits in its count. You can pass `--no-merges` to mirror that.

Comment: Note, on big repositories with over 10,000 commits the line counts (lines added / lines removed) are no longer shown on github > insights > contributors

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility to go to a repository and click on "Contributors"

[image]

Say you are on https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace click on "Contributors" the you get here: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/graphs/contributors where you will get a list of every user saying how many commits he made and how many lines of code he added or removed.